# Right declaration of array of pointers to arrays of char *

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I want to declare of array of pointers to arrays of char *.

When i compile the code, i got warnings:

```
warning: initialization of ‘const char *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘const char **’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

This code works, but i know i do something wrong and i should not have any warnings by C compiler. How to declare it right?

```
const char *S6_ARR[] = {
        "here",
        "we"
};

const char *S7_ARR[] = {
        "go",
        "again"
};

const char *SHEET_HEADER_ARR[] = {
        S6_ARR,
        S7_ARR
};

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Learn about [typedef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef). It makes your code much more readable. Take inspiration from existing open source code, e.g. [GTK](http://gtk.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is telling you that you are trying to put elements of type `const char **` into an array of type `const char *`.  So change the array type to match what you're putting into it:

```
const char **SHEET_HEADER_ARR[] = {
        S6_ARR,
        S7_ARR
};
```